# Forcing user created folders and files to inherit a specific parent folder's groups in macOS

Tags: macos, file-permissions, acl, shared-directory, usergroups

I have multiple users accessing a file system and I need to make sure each time they create a folder it inherits the groups and permissions of the parent folder. Currently each time they create a folder or upload a file the file or folder's group defaults to that user's default group.

Some of these parent folders have multiple groups assigned to them.

Without changing the default group assigned to the user I need to make sure that any folders/files created/uploaded to the system inherit the group(s) of the parent folder.

I have been playing with:

chown

chgrp

chmod -R +a "g:somegroup allow list,file_inherit,directory_inherit,...,..." /file/path

chmod g+s /file/path

But it has not solved the problem. When the users create folders and upload files they are associated with that user's default group.

The issue with this is that if bob creates a folder and then joe tried to use it, joe does not have permission to write in that folder because the default group associated to bob does not have chmod 775 permissions.

That means the folder is only accessible by the owner.

Hoping to have lots of different groups built into the file system for siloing different clients, users, etc with many people having access to everything, so I can't change every user's default group. I need to be able to just add them to the groups they are supposed to be able to write to.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We are also having this issue on a brand new iMac running High Sierra. It is killing us.  I noticed no one answered but I am hoping maybe you found a solution.

Debbie

Comment: I did find a solution but it ended up having a limitation to how many users I could have using the filesystem. (I used bindfs). I am now hoping to find a new resolution to the issue by using macOS to host the file system and a linux computer as the access point to said file system. I'll let you know how it goes and what my final resolution is.